# Can't Accept Text in jQuery Editable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jeditable

I am using the following to create a text field with "Ok" and "Cancel" options for entering new text:

```
 $('.edit_area.entry').first().editable('ajax-save-entry.php', { 
     type      : 'textarea',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'OK',
     indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
 });
```

I have this in the html:

```
'<div id="' . $system->systemID . '" class="edit_area entry">' . $system->description . '</div>'
```

This is ajax-save-entry.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $system = System::find_by_id($_POST['id']);

    if($system){

        $system->description = $_POST['value'];

        $system->save();

        echo $system->description;

        } else {

            echo "Cannot find a system with that system ID";
        }


} else {

echo "No system ID is set";

}

?>
```

I can type text and cancel it, but clicking "Ok" seems to do nothing. I am not sure if the php code is not running or if it is stopping before there. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am using [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

Answer (score 0):

If you could tell us which plugin you're using, that would be optimal. I'm going to assume you're talking about [`this one`](http://plugins.jquery.com/editable/) since it's the most popular/standard (I think).

Anyway, the thing you're missing is a callback function to actually handle what you're echoing onto your php page.

```
$('.edit_area.entry').first().editable('ajax-save-entry.php', { 
     type      : 'textarea',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'OK',
     indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
     callback  : function(data) {
          //the data variable will be whatever your php script echoed
     }
});
```

Comment: I added the function, but it still doesn't seem to work... How can I check which plugin I am using? I am working off of someone else's code, so I didn't pick the one in use.